# Which encoding should I use to save AES encrypted password in property file?

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, base64, decoding

My task is save encrypted password in property file. I have this code and it is working properly, but I am looking for some alternative in Java space. Could somebody give me other properly working encoding than base64?

```
byte[] key = { '^', '(', 'S', '2', 'k', '*', '*','@', 'z', '/', 'a','#', '\\', 'd', 'R', 'G' };
byte[] dataToSend = new String("Hello Bob.").getBytes();
Cipher c;
String s = "";
try {
    c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec k = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
    byte[] encryptedData = c.doFinal(dataToSend);

    s = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encryptedData);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think, you need a different encoding? Does the padding character of Base64 make some problems or is this something else? Please make your question clearer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to Base64 encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777309/alternative-to-base64-encoding)

Comment: `Base64` do not cause any problems. I am asking because I am wondering if exist some alternative in Java like `UTF-8` or `UTF-16` which are not proper in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 takes any data (any charset) and makes it into a very limited charset of only 64 characters, so there's no need to worry about charsets.

There are two types of base64 encoding though, one of which is URL safe.
The other one is not safe because it contains slashes.
If you're concerned, you could use the URL safe base64 encoding rather than the standard one.

Apache Commons Codec provides a URL safe base64 encoder for example.
Or you can download someone's implementation and use that.

You could use Hex Encoding, which will make the encoded string bigger, but  it'll use a smaller character set.